# why doesn't view2 appear in this code? (incorporating UIView 2 within UIView 1)

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, addsubview

Why doesn't view2 appear in this code?  In the result I see the local View1 label shown, at the top with a red border, and within the overall green border, however I see nothing of view2? That is the label with text "View2 Label Text", does NOT appear.

**test11ViewController.m**

```
@implementation test11ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    View1 *view1 = [[[View1 alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 400, 100) ] autorelease];
    view1.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    view1.layer.borderWidth = 1;
    [self.view addSubview:view1];
}
@end
```

**View1.m**

```
@implementation View1
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Local Label
        CGFloat width = self.frame.size.width;
        UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, width, 30)] autorelease];
        label.text = @"View1 Label Text";
        label.layer.borderColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
        label.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
        [self addSubview:label];

        // External - Label2
        View2 *view2 = [[[View2 alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 30, width, 30)] autorelease];
        [super addSubview:view2];   
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

**View2.m**

```
@implementation View2
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        CGFloat width = self.frame.size.width;
        UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, width, 30)] autorelease];
        label.text = @"View2 Label Text";   // Does  NOT appear in output
        label.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
        label.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Comment: as you noticed, I posted a first answer which I soon realised was wrong, and I deleted that answer. Have left a newer answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`view2` isn't actually adding the label to itself. You're missing this:

```
[self addSubview:label];
```

In other words, try:

```
@implementation View2
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        CGFloat width = self.frame.size.width;
        UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, width, 30)] autorelease];
        label.text = @"View2 Label Text";   // Does  NOT appear in output
        label.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
        label.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
        [self addSubview:label];  // NEW LINE HERE
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Comment: arrr - got it - thanks occulus - did you think I could see this  :)

Answer (score 0):

In your test view controller line after...

```
[self.view addSubview:view1];
```

...add...

```
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:view1];
```

Does view2 show now? Alertnately, set the alpha of both views to 0.5 to make sure one is not obscuring the other.